# How to annotate hibernate collections with generic types?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, generics

I have a one-to-many class member of type `List< GenericType < T > >`. What is the recommended way to annotate this member in Hibernate?

Morbid details:

```
@Entity
public class DvOrdered extends DataValue
{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="dv_ordered_other_reference_ranges", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "reference_range_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dv_ordered_id"))
    private List<ReferenceRange<T>> otherReferenceRanges;
}
```

I get

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property com.safehis.ehr.rm.datatypes.quantity.DvOrdered.otherReferenceRanges has an unbound type and no explicit target entity. Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type
at org.hibernate.cfg.PropertyContainer.assertTypesAreResolvable(PropertyContainer.java:140)
at org.hibernate.cfg.PropertyContainer.getProperties(PropertyContainer.java:118)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.addElementsOfClass(AnnotationBinder.java:1554)
at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:236)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
```

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: What have you tried and whats the error that you are getting? As a side note do you really have oneToMany with a generic type !!!!

Comment: Could you please provide the involved classes?

Comment: Added details about one error,

Comment: Error makes perfect sense . It does not know which concrete entity the relationship is with .

Comment: I'm sure the error makes sense. The question however asks how to write this type of idiom.

Comment: 'Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic information is lost at compile-time due, to type erasure so Hibernate can't figure out what type `T` is in your case.

You can change your code to this:

```
private List<ReferenceRange<T>> otherReferenceRanges;
```

And then use inheritance so that each `ReferenceRange` subclass embeds a certain type.

```
public abstract class ReferenceRange<T> {

    public abstract T getReference();
}

public class IntegerReferenceRange extends ReferenceRange<Integer> {

    private Integer reference;

    @Override
    public Integer getReference() {
        return reference;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't understand how this helps. Is there a way to use Hibernate AnyMetaDef with a OneToMany association and then use, say, ReferenceRange < Integer > as you suggest as a MetaValue?

Comment: Using `@AnyMetaDef` gives you the same effect as if using inheritance, but you won;t be able to use nested generic types.